# How can I remove the value from an element with javascript/typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

This is my progress bar:

```
<progress class="progress is-small" value="20" max="100">20%</progress>
```

I want to remove `value="20"` with javascript, so that the result will be

```
<progress class="progress is-small" max="100">20%</progress>
```

The reason why I want to do this is, that I'd like to get an indeterminate progress bar (https://bulma.io/documentation/elements/progress/) by clicking another element.

I tried `document.getElementsByTagName("progress").val("");`but this is not working.

Comment: You're looking for ```element.removeAttribute('value');```

Comment: I tested it, but I get the error message TS2339: Property 'removeAttribute' does not exist on type 'HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLProgressElement>'.

Comment: I've tried it in vanilla JS, I've attached runnable code in my answer below. Please check. @peace_love

Comment: Ah, now I see where you went wrong. You've used `getElementsByTagName`, which gave you a list of all the `progress` elements in the page, not just one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the [removeAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute) function.

From the docs:

```
// Given: <div id="div1" align="left" width="200px">
document.getElementById("div1").removeAttribute("align");
// Now: <div id="div1" width="200px">
```

**Code**

I've edited the code to target all progressbars in the page.

```js
const progressbars = document.getElementsByTagName('progress');
const button = document.getElementById('btn');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < progressbars.length; i++) {
    progressbars[i].removeAttribute('value');
  }
});
```

```html
<progress id="bar1" value="20" max="100"></progress>
<progress id="bar2" value="20" max="100"></progress>
<progress id="bar3" value="20" max="100"></progress>
<progress id="bar4" value="20" max="100"></progress>
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is, that I cannot get the element by ID. Because there are multiple items added to a list. Is there a way to get all progress elements instead of one ID?

Comment: I've edited the code to target all progressbars in the page. Please check the code snippet! @peace_love

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("progress").removeAttribute('value');
```

Comment: I tested it, but I get the error message TS2339: Property 'removeAttribute' does not exist on type 'HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLProgressElement>'.